# Error message finding required files during PHP Mailer execution on server

Tags: php, composer-php, phpmailer

I am getting an errors when trying send an email with PHP Mailer. I followed a tutorial that utilizes local host to test, however, I am testing on a live server. I believe that the way my directories are set up may be causing the issues. I installed PHP Mailer into the directory using Composer and uploaded the entire directory onto the server. Here are the errors I am getting:

```
[16-Jan-2018 08:36:33] PHP Warning:  require_once(__DIR__/composer/autoload_real.php)
[<a href='function.require-once'>function.require-once</a>]:
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /public_html/netWorks/emailtests/vendor/autoload.php on line 5

[16-Jan-2018 08:36:33] PHP Fatal error:  require_once() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]:
Failed opening required '__DIR__/composer/autoload_real.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib64/php:/usr/share/pear') in
/public_html/netWorks/emailtests/vendor/autoload.php on line 5
```

Here is index.php -

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';                       // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'kevin@kevin.com';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'PW0RD';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('kmoriarty@kevin.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('kevin@kevin.com', 'Kevin');     // Add a recipient
    $mail->addReplyTo('kevin@kevin.com', 'Email Master Flex');
    //$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    //$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

    //Attachments
    //$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
    //$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'You are receiving this because...';
    $mail->Body    = 'Stack Overflow is <b>AWESOME!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'You are receiving this because Stack Overflow is AWESOME!';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

I tried changing the directory for autoload to /vendor/autoload.php but that also failed.

My parent folder has the vendor folder, composer.json, composer.lock and my index.php. Inside the vendor folder is the composer folder, the phpmailer folder and autoload.php. Is there a chance that this is where I am running into issues?

I have upgraded to PHP version 5.6 - I am now getting this error:

```
[16-Jan-2018 09:23:03 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPMailer' not found in /public_html/netWorks/emailtests/index.php on line 4
```

Comment: Thanks for the edits... Sorry for being sloppy.

Comment: That is a little odd. It uses `__DIR__` which was introduced in PHP 5.3, and will render to a literal string in older versions, which looks like what's happening to you; Are you using a version of PHP older than that? If so, upgrade **now**!

Comment: Current PHP version: 5.2.17 ... I will upgrade and see if that helps.

Comment: Wow, PHP 5.2.17... End of life was 6 years ago... Straight from an history book.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to advise from Synchro on upgrading PHP I was able to resolve. I also needed to add namespacing:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
```